# How to automate the configuration process of Windows Server 2016?

Tags: powershell, configuration, automation, installation, windows-server

I need to setup and configure some Windows Server 2016 VMs. The tasks include:

- Execute c:\windows\system32\sysprep\sysprep\sysprep.exe
- Configure the administrator password
- Rename the guest VM
- Set fixed IP address
- Add it into a domain
- Install some software in the VMs

Right now I have to do all the steps manually which is boring and error-prone. I can use PowerShell to automate some steps but some tasks require a reboot of the OS so I don't know whether it it possible to automate the whole process. Can someone point me in the right direction? I've heard of some configuration management tools like Ansible or Chef etc, but I don't have experience in those. Can they solve my problem?

Comment: Why dont you just execute all steps and reboot after everything is finished, the tasks you listed should have no problem with this

Comment: sysprep requires me to reboot and setup the language and administrator password etc. All other steps can only happen after that.

Comment: why do you need to sysprep as the first step?

Comment: @4c74356b41 Because these VMs are cloned from a template. Without executing sysprep, they all have the same sid which will cause some problems later. sysprep can generate a new sid for each VM. You can check the sid using this tool at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psgetsid

Comment: i'm not asking what\why sysprep. I'm asking why dont you sysprep the template?

Comment: Will sysprep the template give me a new sid for each cloned VM? I'm not sure of that but I'll test later.

Comment: Sysprep with shutdown option will give you an OOBE [out of the box experience]. A template should not have an SID so sysprep-ing the template is the standard procedure. Now when you clone and turn it on, the new machine goes through the entire setup process.

Comment: i think you should look into MDT. You can execute custom scripts in the deployment process to set a static IP etc.